# Get value from a JS string

Tags: javascript

I have a string, example "hello word:abc there"

I need to get the value after the value 'word:', so in the above case the answer would be 'abc'.

"abc xyz word:2 hhh yyy" = '2'

etc.

Comment: Fascinating. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use `substring()`, `split()` with some Regex and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
var yourString="hello word:1235 tsfa";
var patt1=/:(\w*)/;
alert(yourString.match(patt1)[1]);
```

working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/J843X/)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)